# I want to change the navigation transition time, but found that it does not take effect on Android

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I was using reactnavigation to make an Android application. I felt that the navigation switching time was too long, so I went to set the time and found that it did not take effect on Android.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPyWb.jpg)

I want to be able to modify the transition time of the navigation based on the time I set